# Using hashes as instance variables

Tags: ruby, hash

I am very new to Ruby.

When using hashes as instance variables is it

```
class Hero
  def initialize (stats={})
```

Or

```
class Hero
  def initialize (stats={'Atk':0, 'Def':0})
```

Or

```
class Hero
  def initialize (stats)
```

Or some better way? I am getting around 30 errors on the initialize line about unexpected ':' etc.

There are probably 10 hashes in the initialize line. Is it better to have an individual variable for each state instead? Thanks in advance!

Sorry if this is a duplicate but I haven't seen any questions about this.

My Class:

```
class Hero

  attr_accessor :nam, :desc, :race, :clas, :bg, :heroLVL, :hitpoints, :armC, :spd, :sdcwic, :modifiers, :proficiencies, :skills, :languages, :inventory, :equipment, :coins, :features, :feats, :spellsKnown, :spellSlots, :maxSpellSlots, :currentSpellSlots, :cantrips

  def initialize(nam, desc = {}, race, clas = [], bg, heroLVL = {}, hitpoints = {'Current HP' : 0, 'Max HP' : 0, 'Temp HP' : 0}, armC, spd, sdcwic = {'Stre' : 0, 'Dex' : 0, 'Con' : 0, 'Wis' : 0, 'Int' : 0, 'Cha' : 0}, modifiers = {'Stre' : 0, 'Dex' : 0, 'Con' : 0, 'Wis' : 0, 'Int' : 0, 'Cha' : 0, 'Proficiency' : 0}, proficiencies = [], skills = {}, languages = [], inventory = {}, equipment = {}, coins = {'Copper' : 0, 'Silver' : 0, 'Electrum' : 0, 'Gold' : 0, 'Platinum' : 0}, features = [], feats = [], spellsKnown = [], spellSlots = {}, maxSpellSlots = {}, currentSpellSlots = {}, cantrips = [])
    #description
    @nam = nam
    @desc = desc
    #stats
    @race = race
    @clas = clas 
    @bg = bg
    @heroLVL = heroLVL
    @hitpoints = hitpoints
    @armC = armC
    @spd = spd
    #modifiers
    @sdcwic = sdcwic
    @modifiers = modifiers
    @proficiencies = proficiencies
    @skills = skills
    @languages = languages
    #inventory
    @inventory = inventory
    @equipment = equipment
    @coins = coins
    #features
    @features = features
    @feats = feats
    #casting
    @spellsKnown = spellsKnown
    @spellSlots = spellSlots
    @maxSpellSlots = maxSpellSlots
    @currentSpellSlots = currentSpellSlots
    @cantrips = cantrips
  end
end
```

Comment: Sorry. In my actual code that space is not there.

Comment: Please add new code to your question using the `edit` link just below the tags. Also, that `initialize` definition doesn't have a closing parenthesis. Is that incomplete? And, can you please show a sample `new` call?

Comment: Yes. Too many characters to fit.

Comment: Edited with the initialize line.

Comment: Can you add a sample `Hero.new` call?

Comment: I actually haven't got that far to include the new call

Comment: The error is unexpected ':' expected keyword end

Comment: Edited to show the class and initialize method.

Comment: You only have one end. You need one end for class and another for the initialize method.

Comment: There are other methods below. So the class end is not shown.

Answer (score -1):

It's

```
class Hero
  def initialize (stats)
    @stats = stats
  end
```

Assuming stats is a hash like, { name: "Generic Hero name, hp: 400, ... }. Also, Ruby has something called "keyword arguments". So if you pass name: "Hero", hp: 400, ... etc into a method, it's all automatically converted into a single hash.

EDIT: Don't pass it in as an argument, just set it inside the class itself. If you actually aren't passing any stats and just want a blank state, there's no point passing it in. If you ARE passing in values rather than just empty arrays/hashes, you should pass in the entire stats variable then just assign using @name = stats[name].

```
def initialize
  @desc = {}
  @class = []
  ...
end
```

Etc.

Comment: In this case where do the keys and values get populated?

Comment: Inside the stats instance method? Then if you want to access the hero name, you do @stats[name], etc.

Comment: Ok this makes more sense. Thanks. I was under the impression that they had to have defaults.

Answer (score -1):

I think you ought to make this easy on yourself and do something like:

```
class Hero 

  def initialize(stats={})
    stats.each do |k,v|
      class_eval { attr_accessor k }
      send("#{k}=",v)
    end
  end

end
```

Note that looping the `stats` saves you about 450 characters. And, your code is much cleaner.

You would call `Hero` something like:

```
Hero.new name: 'billy', 
         race: 'elf',
         desc: {},
         clas: []
```

Note that **everything** is in the `key: value` form. And, every `key` gets turned into a method on the instance of `Hero` that will return the `value` that was passed in.

So, if you do:

```
@hero = Hero.new name: 'billy', 
                 race: 'elf',
                 desc: {},
                 clas: []
```

Then you will be able to do:

```
@hero.name
 -> billy
```

This will fail, BTW, if you try to call `@hero.spellsKnown` because (in this example) there is no `key: value` pair with a `key` of `spellsKnown`. So, you could go back to using `attr_accessor`, something like:

```
class Hero 

  attr_accessor *%w(
    name desc race clas bg heroLVL hitpoints armC spd sdcwic modifiers 
    proficiencies skills languages inventory equipment coins features 
    feats spellsKnown spellSlots maxSpellSlots currentSpellSlots cantrips
  ).freeze

  def initialize(stats={})
    stats.each do |k,v|
      send("#{k}=",v)
    end
  end

end
```

Now you will be fine if you call `spellsKnown`.

Also BTW, you might want to take a look at the [Ruby style guide](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide). Names like `spellsKnown` and `hitpoints` are not conventional ruby. They should be more like `spells_known` and `hit_points`, respectively.

And, I know it can seem painful, but I suggest you spell things out completely. `nam` should be `name`. Later, you won't have to try to remember what truncations you used.

Comment: I'm still very new to coding and general. So I'm working on the logic but this looks great. Thanks! I may be in over my head but it's a fun way to pass the time.

Comment: I try to stay away from naming variables with keywords such as main class and name. Seems bad to use variable names that can be mistaken for keywords.